# How to compute $\mathbb{E} \left[ (W_s + W_t - 2W_0)^2 \right]$?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

The solution to the SDE

$$dx_t= -kx_t dt + cx_t dW_t$$

is

$$x_t = x_0 e^{\left(c - \frac{k^2}{2} \right)t}e^{-k W_t}$$

with mean

$$\mathbb{E} \left[ x_t \right] = x_0 e^{\left(c - \frac{k^2}{2}\right)t}$$

where $W_)$ is the Wiener process.

I'm looking to compute

$\mathbb{E} \left[ (W_s + W_t - 2W_0)^2 \right]$

but am unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: I don't see how the computation of the expectation is related to the solution of the GBM SDE...

Answer (score 8):

I would calculate it this way,

$\mathbb{E}[(W_s+W_t−2W_0)^2] = \mathbb{E}\left[\left((W_s-W_0)+(W_t-W_0)\right)^2\right]\\ 
\hspace{4cm}=\mathbb{E}[(W_s-W_0)^2]+\mathbb{E}[(W_t-W_0)^2]+2\mathbb{E}[(W_s-W_0)(W_t-W_0)] \\
\hspace{4cm}=s+t+2\mathbb{E}[W_sW_t]\\
\hspace{4cm}=s+t+2\min(s,t)$

Comment: How do you come to $E(W_s,W_t)=\min(s,t)$?

Comment: Assume WLOG that $s<t$ then $E[W_sW_t]=E[W_s (W_t - W_s )+W_s^2]$ independent increments and the distributional properties and you are done.

Comment: @Henrik I see that formula, but it does not depend on $s<t$, you can rewrite it both ways getting $E(W_sW_t)=s=t$ which is obviously wrong if $s<t$?

Comment: @emcor: Henrik answer is right! The formula depends on $s<t$. Indeed, $(W_t-W_s)$ is independent of $W_s$, it's Markov property that says that $(W_t-W_s)$ behave as a new brownien process independent of all what happens in the past $F_s$. Due to this, $\mathbb{E}[W_s(W_t-W_s)]=\mathbb{E}[W_s]\mathbb{E}[(W_t-W_s)]=0$.

Comment: @aajajim I still dont agree. Let $s>t$. Then $(W_t-W_s)=-(W_s-W_t)$ which also has expectation zero.

Comment: @aajajim "Assume WLOG that $s>t$ then $E[W_sW_t]=E[W_s(W_t−W_s)+W_s^2]$ independent increments and the distributional properties and you are done." What is wrong with that? If its correct, Henrik must be wrong because $\min(s,t)\neq s$ here.

Comment: @emcor: The problem here is that you want to write $W_sW_t$ in anthor way, and it will great if the new way you find, uses process that are independent! THE ONLY WAY you can do this is to make an assumption on the order of $t$ and $s$. If $s<t$ the $W_sW_t = W_s(W_t-W_s) + W_s^2$, but if $s>t$ the $W_sW_t = W_t(W_s-W_t) + W_t^2$. Then you use the independence of a brownien process $(B_y - B_x)$ of all what happend in $[0,x]$ including $B_x$. You can see, that depending on the situation, you will have to compute $\mathbb{E}[W_s^2]$ of $\mathbb{E}[W_t^2]$ which equals to $s$ or $t$.

Comment: @emcor: It's Stochastic Calculus basics. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139260/independence-of-bt-bs-with-respect-to-mathcalf-s

Comment: @aajajim Is it correct to summarise what you said as: '$W_s$ and $W_t - W_s$ are not independent if $s > t$ eg $W_{5}$ and $W_{10} - W_{5}$ are independent but $W_{10}$ and $W_{5} - W_{10}$ are not independent' ?

Answer (score -1):

Your solution $x_t$ is wrong.

Your mean is wrong too.  Note that $\mathbb{E}\left[ e^{W_t}\right] = e^\frac{t}{2}$.  I corrected the typo that was pointed out by Richard.

Comment: $W_t$ is Gaussian - right? Then $E[e^{W_t}]$ is just the moment generating function of a Gaussian random variable with variance $t$ evaluated at $1$. So your formula is wrong.

Comment: $E[e^{W_t}] = \exp(t^2/2)$.

Comment: Richard: thanks for pointing out the typo.  If $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, $\mathbb{E}\left[e^X\right] = e^{\mu + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2}$.

Comment: Richard: Note that $W_t \sim N\Big(0, \big(\sqrt{t}\big)^2\Big)$. Then $E\big(e^{W_t} \big) = e^{\frac{t}{2}}$.